# Woocommerce разное поведение списка товаров на главной и в каталоге

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на Woocommerce. Каталог должен отображаться как на страницах магазина (/shop, /product-category и т.д.) Поведение каталога - разное. На страницах магазина - стандартно, с пагинацией, тут нет проблем. На главной же - по умолчанию сколько-то товаров и тычка "Показать ещё три":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фильтры и вывод товаров сейчас с плагином WOO filters
Как реализовать?

C ajax не умею работать напрямую, подсказывайте поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо добавить кнопку на страницу. Клик обрабатывать в своём js файле, из которого вызывать через ajax код php. Код php будет возвращать дополнительно 3 товара в js-код, который будет их добавлять в область отображения на странице.

Инструкция на русском по созданию ajax в WordPress находится [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Можете попробовать использовать плагин [WordPress Infinite Scroll — Ajax Load More](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/).